# In SAP how can I get the real IP address of a user connecting via VPN

Tags: ip-address, vpn, sap-gui, sap-erp

Here is the scenario. a User accesses enterprise SAP system on the intranet by logging onto the intranet via VPN. The SAP needs to know the real user IP (not the one that VPN assigned to him).

How can we find the real IP address?
Does the VPN pass real or 'vpn-assigned' IP address to SAP?

Finally is it possible to configure the VPN such that it passes real client IP addresses (i.e. as visible to the VPN) to the intranet applications.

Comment: the method of connection is actually the key to problem. You dont say how they are connected to the sap system. RFC, SAPGUI , HTTP ?

Comment: Thanks phil. They could be connected either using SAPGUI or HTTP.

Comment: I have no clue of SAP but only networking. And I would say there is no way from the receiving side of the TCP connection, as all the knowledge about the "real" IP of the user is inside the VPN gateway.

Comment: There is no such thing as "**the** real IP" - and this is not a limitation of SAP or any other technology stack. For example, my Laptop frequently has two ways to connect to the internet, via WLAN and via cable, with two different IP addresses - which one is the real one? And as soon as NAT comes into play, you won't even be able to see anything beyond a certain point. What do you need the IP address for?

Comment: @StephenKing & vwegert Thank you both. Is there anyway the VPN can pass on the IP that it sees as opposed to assigning an IP to the user?

Answer (score 0):

For SAPGUI try CALL FUNCTION 'TERMINAL_ID_GET'

For the Web Call, I normal put a simple exit on the Handler in SICF. The access Server->Request the get the headers.  You should find the callers Ip.